# what's wrong with this approach re referencing another project in Xcode 4?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, xcode4

I'm trying to reference another Xcode4 project within Xcode4 but having troubles - what's I'm currently doing is as follows:

- In project B in XCode4 I drag in project A (from Finder) into project B
- In project B's main target, in Build Phases / Target Dependencies I add/select my project A's main target.
- I put an, #import "myProjectAClass", in one of my project B files
- when I compile I can an ERROR "myProjectAClass no such file or directory"

Any suggestions?  What is the minimum number of places I need to touch/adjust in XCode4 project configuration such that I can start using clases from project B in project A, and it will all compile?

Comment: Try with any header file and add .h -->                     #import "myProjectAClass.h"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading this correctly I had the same issue the other night. Except that I was dealing with two targets, one that built a static library and the other that ran an app to executes tests on the static lib. Here's what I did

- Target A builds a static lib.
- Target B runs a unit testing suite for testing target A's static lib.

In target B's settings:

1. Add Target A as a dependency. This ensures that it is built first. (I think :) )
2. Add the static library (libA.a) from Target A to Target B's **Link Binary With Libraries** list along with any frameworks the lib needs.

The second item is the important one. Adding a dependency (as I understand it) doesn't automatically include any of Target A's output to Target B's linking phase.

Comment: thanks Derek - when I add the *.a file into the "Link Binary With Libraries" area and build I get a "ld: library not found for -llibrary" error?  I note the *.a file shows up as red with a blank checkbox to the left of it in the "Link Binary With Libraries".  Also the project navigation left hand panel the *.a file shows up as red with a blank checkbox to the left of it too.  Any ideas

Comment: No idea. Mine show up as red too. I've not looked into why. I'd guess that perhaps there is something wrong with the lb you are including. But that's just a guess. I just did a google search on your error message and found quite a number of people with the same error. I' suggest doing the same and read through their discussions to see if any match what you are doing.

Comment: thanks - I think I've got a bit further along now - I'll make this one as accepted - I have a more specific question re where I'm stuck now at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195455/why-do-i-get-these-errors-building-a-static-library-for-my-iphone-project-using-x

Comment: The red library thing is a bug in Xcode 4. I posted a workaround to it; read this thread on Apple's Developer Forums: https://devforums.apple.com/message/418894