# why do I get this error building a static library for my iPhone project using XCode 4?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios, xcode4

I have an existing iPhone application, and I just wanted to make a static library out of the code, so that I can use it by a separate test application (within the workspace).  The application compiles fine, but when I try to compile the library version (which has the same code files) I get the following error:

- Lexical or Preprocessor Issue - "MyClass.h" file not found

However, the application still runs, even through there is this error.  In fact when I compile the application (which uses the static library) it initially says no errors, and then after a second or two the above mention error then appears.

I'm basically doing:

1. Create a new target in the project using the Coco Touch Static Library
2. Add the .m files in the targets "Compile Sources"
3. Adding the .h files in the targets "Copy Headers"
4. Adding the same set of libraries in the "Link binaries with libraries"
5. Go into the Profile and modified the Target to be RELEASE

Any suggestions?  Am I missing a step here?

Comment: Please post the actual errors. It's hard to tell exactly what's going wrong otherwise. Are you `#import`ing all the headers you need into your implementation files?

Comment: I have to agree with jtbandes, we need more information in order to help you.

Comment: well I've updated the question as I did make it one step further, hopefully this makes it a bit more specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the issue turned out to be I had "-ObjC" set in the "Other Link Flags" option, which I'd put there as at one stage trying to get things working I read this was required - Dereks advice to review the compilation log worked well here

Answer (score 4):

I'll have a stab at this :-) I think it might be that MyClass.h has been set to private. Thus it is not added to header directory when you create the static library. You should check to see if this is so by checking the output header directory. If the header file is missing, then it's pretty sure thats whats going on.

Secondly, why use a seperate app for testing and therefore require building a static library at all? I have several static libraries and apps which I unit test with [GHUnit](http://gabriel.github.com/gh-unit/). I do it by simply adding a new app target and configuring it to run the GHUnit iOS app. I can then add the classes I want to test and any testing frameworks such as [OCMock](http://www.mulle-kybernetik.com/software/OCMock/) without having to create separate projects. Basically it sounds like your testing methodolody is perhaps more complex than necessary. :-)

Comment: actually Derek where do I look for output header directory do you know?  I doesn't seem obvious to me as I'm looking through Finder...   Regarding background, already have some unit tests, but I've got memory leak issues and wanted a way to run Instruments over selected library functions.

Comment: Um, don't have my mac in front of me, but there is a build setting that sets where headers are copied to. Also when you select the header file, XCode shows you which targets it belongs to and next to that it has a pulldown with private, protected and public. By default I think it sets headers as private and you have to change it for any headers you want available to users of your library. Oh, another way to find out where things go is to expand the compilation log lines to display the actual command line used in each step.

Comment: thanks Derek - in going through your advice I found the issue - I posted this as the answer - thanks for helping